# let $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ be two rows of Real numbers with properties:

Tags: sequences-and-series

let $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ be two rows of Real numbers with properties: (So in R)

- $\lvert a_n\rvert\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$;
- $(b_n )$  has a limitpoint $v$.

  Let $(c_n )$  be a row given by $c_n=a_n b_n$, $n \in\mathbb N$. Show that $(c_n )$  has a limitpoint $z$ which statisfy $\lvert z\rvert\le M\lvert v\rvert$

I used the following: limit theorem $a_nb_n$ $\rightarrow$ a* b*. After this i used the limit definition of sequences  $\forall$_$\epsilon$>0$\exists$_$n_0$_$\in$N$\forall$_n$\ge$n_0 : $\lvert a_n-a*\rvert$ < $\epsilon$

But i get stuck into bring these facts towards a systematic step to include Cn and show $\lvert z\rvert\le M\lvert v\rvert$

Comment: How do you define a limit point?

Comment: And more to the point: Why should we care? What do you think? What did you try? What do you think might be useful?

Comment: @Carsten S:  "limit point" is a standard and pretty basic concept in calculus. It means the sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @mathguy, thanks. I thought so, but I want to make sure as someone who attempted (and in the meantime deleted) an answer apparently read it as limit. (And I do not always remember terminology correctly, I would probably have called it an accumulation point as that is nearer to the German *Häufungspunkt*.)

Comment: Please note that (An), (Bn) are not a subset of the Naturel numbers but of are two rows in R.

Comment: Where you write "row" I think in English it is more usual to write "sequence."  I am trying to guess the foreign word that makes you think "row" is appropriate -- ряд?

Comment: @John $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is common notation for a sequence. It doesn't imply that $a_n\in\mathbb N$!

Comment: @ProbablyWrong alright but why such a confusing notation?

Comment: @John It indicates that the sequence is indexed by the natural numbers.

Comment: @ProbablyWrong   used the following: limit theorem anbn → a* b*. After this i used the limit definition of sequences ∀_ϵ>0∃_n0_∈N∀_n≥n_0 : ∣an−a∗∣ < ϵ

But i get stuck into bring these facts towards a systematic step to include Cn and show ∣z∣≤M∣v∣

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that every bounded sequence has a limit point. $\{a_n\}$ is bounded by hypothesis, and $\{b_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence, which means the subsequence is also bounded. So now only use the subsequence of $\{c_n\}$ that corresponds to the convergent subsequence of $\{b_n\}$. This means the subsequence of $\{c_n\}$ is bounded, so it has a convergent sub-subsequence. Which is also a subsequence of $\{c_n\}$ (a subsequence of a subsequence of a sequence is also a subsequence of the big sequence).

Comment: let (an)n∈N, (bn)n∈N be two rows of Real numbers with properties This should not be in the question as An and Bn are two rows in R

Comment: I dont know how the N came there ... ?

Comment: I used the theorems  used the following: limit theorem anbn → a* b*. After this i used the limit definition of sequences ∀_ϵ>0∃_n0_∈N∀_n≥n_0 : ∣an−a∗∣ < ϵ

But i get stuck into bring these facts towards a systematic step to include Cn and show ∣z∣≤M∣v∣